# QT offline installer version misunderstanding

Tags: qt

Trying to download Qt offline installer since online failed installation.

Trying to download from official releases: https://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.9/5.9.5/
But why there is version 5.9.5 while default online installer is ver 3.0.4 ?

Answer (score 1):

The online installer is a tool, and the current version is 3.0.4. It can download any Qt version from the internet (hence *online*)

The offline installer has everything you need for a specific Qt version (e.g. 5.9.5) packed in the installer (hence *offline*).

For each Qt version that the single online installer can install, there will be a separate offline installer.

Answer (score 0):

By downloading the online installer you are becoming able to use the **online Qt installer** not the Qt itself. Downloading it is

By using online Qt installer you can install lots of things about Qt like Qt designer Qt 5.10.1, Qt 5.4.2 etc. And These are inside the Qt online installer.

Do not worry about the version of the online installer. It has the latest Qt version.(Beside the old ones).

If you are not sure what you are doing. You can use this link to download Qt:

https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/